# some help in fixing this error...I was tring to install ng-angular-popup and NgConfirm modules....when serving the project im getting this error

Tags: angular14

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjH9H.png)Error: node_modules/ng-angular-popup/lib/ng-toast.component.d.ts:14:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

14     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgToastComponent, "lib-ng-toast", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>;

Error: node_modules/ng-confirm-box/lib/ng-confirm.component.d.ts:12:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

12     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgConfirmComponent, "ng-confirm", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>;

I tried to force install this modules but still the error persists

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded **ng-angular-popup** to **v0.2.0** and it worked with Angular 14.